# Cómo obtener la fecha inicial y la última de una lista de fechas

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
List<LocalDate> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-02-16"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-02-16"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-02-17"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-03-01"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-03-29"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-04-01"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-04-03"));
listDate.add(LocalDate.parse("2023-04-28"));
```

¿cómo puedo filtrar esta fecha por mes desde el más reciente al más antiguo?

ejemplo: ['2023-02-16', 2023-02-17, 2023-03-01, 2023-03-29, 2023-04-01, 2023-04-28]

Sólo necesito obtener de un mes la primera fecha y la última.

cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int menor = 0;
int mayor = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < listDate.size() - 1; i++ ) {
   if( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( listDate.get( menor ), listDate.get( i + 1 ) ) < 0 ) {
      menor = i  +1;
   }
   if( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( listDate.get( mayor ), listDate.get( i + 1 ) ) > 0 ) {
      mayor = i +1;
   }
}

LocalDate fechaAnterior = listDate.get( menor );
LocalDate fechaPosterior = listDate.get( mayor );
System.out.println( fechaAnterior + " " + fechaPosterior );
```

El método **ChronoUnit.DAYS.between** devuelve la diferencia en días, entre dos fechas, si la primera es mayor, el valor devuelto será negativo.